# Use variable to trigger function with the same name in javascript (or jQuery)

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have a function with a name, like this:

```
function tony {
   //do something
}
```

I also have a variable called currentName with the value 'tony', like this:

```
var currentName = 'tony';
```

What I want to know is whether there's any way of activating the `tony ()` function by using the variable `currentName` eg: `+currentName+ ();` (but I know that doesn't work)?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a JavaScript function named in a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723287/calling-a-javascript-function-named-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's in the global scope, you can use...

```
window[currentName]();
```

Comment: Wait, this wasn't a `yes` or `no` question? ;)  +1.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
eval(currentName + '()');
```

Comment: Yeah, I know it should be avoided. Alex's solution is probably also more efficient. :)