# Can I use the value of a variable to initiate a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling a JavaScript function named in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723287/calling-a-javascript-function-named-in-a-variable)

I want to use the value of a variable as the call to initiate a function, but I'm not sure if it is possible?

say I have:

```
function myFunction(){
    // Do something
}

var functionName = "myFunction";
functionName(); // This should run the function named myFunction
```

Is this something that can be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do a few things:

```
//if the function is in the global scope:

window["myFunction"](); 
//or
var functionName = "myFunction";
window[functionName]();
```

Or maintain your own map:

```
var functions = {
    myFunction: function() {
        ...
    },
    ...
    myOtherFunction: function() {
        ...
    }
};
```

Then either of the following will work:

```
functions.myFunction(); //will work
functions["myFunction"](); //will also work;

var functionName = "myFunction";
functions[functionName](); //also works
```

Of course, you can use `eval`:

```
eval(functionName + "()");
```

But `eval` is dangerous and I **don't** recommend it.

**Based on your fiddle**

Your `right` and `left` functions have been defined in the local scope of an anonymous function. This means that they are **not** part of the global `window` object. You should use the second method I described above (constructing your own map):

```
var directions = {
    right: function() {
        ...
    },
    left: function() {
        ...
    }
    ...
};

var direction = "right";
directions[direction]();
```

Comment: I trie this but I got the following error;
'Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method "direction"'

Comment: Do you have a function called direction?

Comment: I have a function called right. The variable called direction has a value of right. I want to run my function.

Comment: You will need to use `window[direction]();`. Notice the lack of quotes :)

Comment: Hmm I did this but then got the error: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'left' of object [object Window] is not a function.

Maybe something to do with the structure of my functions, here's a jsfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/CMGmj/)

EDIT: See original fiddle not /1!

Comment: your `direction` var is set to `"left"`.  If you have `var myFuncs = { right : function () {}, left : function () {} };` and `var direction = "right";` then `myFuncs[direction]();` will work.  If `right` or `left` isn't a function, and you call it, then you're going to get an error.

Comment: @ACynicalGeek Check out my edit. Basically your functions have been defined in the local scope of an anonymous function and not in the global scope.

Comment: @VivinPaliath thank you for all your help. Following your advice I'm getting closer. I've now got to the point where I'm re-structuring the entire code.

I have a template for a jQuery plugin and I think I'm probably better doing it that way as opposed to this horrible inline scripting I'm doing.

I haven't figured it out yet, but you've really helped me out!

Comment: @VivinPaliath I got it to work! Thank you so much. I've included the jsFiddle so you can see :) [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CMGmj/3/)

Comment: @ACynicalGeek Good to hear! :)