# Execute functions whose names are in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've seen [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string), [Calling a JavaScript function named in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723287/calling-a-javascript-function-named-in-a-variable), [Can I use the value of a variable to initiate a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504037/can-i-use-the-value-of-a-variable-to-initiate-a-function?lq=1), but I can't figure out how to get this working with an array and a for loop.

What I've tried:

I have a few functions, let's say:

```
function one() { 
    alert('one');
}

function two() {
    alert('two');
}

function three() {
    alert('three');
}
```

and an array:

```
callThese = ['one', 'two']
```

and I want to call `one` and `two`.

This doesn't work:

```
for (i = 0; i < callThese.length; ++i) {
    //console.log(callThese[i]); <--- (outputs one and two)
    window[callThese[i]]();
}
```

The error I get is `TypeError: object is not a function`. The functions are definitely there, and they work by calling them manually (ie. `one()`, `two()`, etc...).

Sorry if this is a basic mistake, but how do I get this working?? I don't mind a jQuery solution if there is one.

Comment: newbies seem to do this quite often, use function names stored in strings, and then wanting to call the functions. **Don't** , there are surely better ways to do this, for instance storing actual references to the functions instead of strings.

Comment: If it says `object is not a function` then `window[callThese[i]]` is not a function. What is it?

Comment: The error suggests the functions aren't globals. If they're defined within another `function`, they won't be properties of `window`.

Comment: @Halcyon `callThese[i]` should equals `one` and `two`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski They're defined in an `if`

Comment: @ṧнʊß yes, but what is `window.one`, `window.two`, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign functions to your object. It's not recommended to create global functions (other scripts/frameworks can overwrite them).

```
var obj = {
        one: function () {
            alert('one');
        },
        two: function () {
            alert('two');
        },
        three: function () {
            alert('three');
        }
    },
    callThese = ['one', 'two'];

for (var i = 0; i < callThese.length; ++i) {
    obj[callThese[i]]();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object that contains the functions

```
var myFuncs = {
    one: function () {
        alert('one');
    },
    two: function () {
        alert('two');
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < callThese.length; ++i) {        
    myFuncs[callThese[i]]();
}
```