# How to invoke function call if it is defined as var?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting data from server using JQuery and JSON. I defined `getBooksDoneFunc`
as variable because I need to be able to call this function not only once (when `getBooks` is done) . Unfortunately, I cannot call `getBooksDoneFunc` from inside of `signInOK` as `window["getBooksDoneFunc"]();`. Why? What is the best way to call this function?

```
function getBooks(){     return $.getJSON( "bookstore.json" );             }

var getBooksDoneFunc = function(json) { 
         $.each(json.books, function(i, json){ .......... });

}

getBooks().done(getBooksDoneFunc);

function signInOK(){
         window["getBooksDoneFunc"]();
}
```

PS. The idea for `window["getBooksDoneFunc"]();` was taken from [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723287/calling-a-javascript-function-named-in-a-variable)

UPDATE:

```
var booksJSON = {};
window["getBooksDoneFunc"](booksJSON);
```

`getBooksDoneFunc` must be called with parameters nevertheless the call to `getBooksDoneFunc` fails. `signInOK` is defined outside of `$(document).ready(function(){ });` but called inside of it.

Comment: If this is all done enclosed in another function, say, `$(document).ready(function(){...});`, then `getBooksDoneFunc` won't exist under `window`.

Comment: @ahren sounds like an answer...

Comment: @kojiro - unfortunately not, since I didn't answer the question *"How to invoke function call if it is defined as var?"* or *"What is the best way to call this function?"*

Comment: Thanks for the remark, indeed my func `signInOK()` is called inside `$(document).ready` while all other functions is defined outside of `$(document).ready`

Comment: Your getBooksDoneFunc() function takes one argument but you attempt to call without any inside signInOK().

Comment: @ahren, how to call func if *it is not exist under `window`*?

Comment: What is the failure message? If the call succeeds but is made with no parameters then `json` is undefined and your `$.each` will throw an error about not being able to get the length to iterate over as `json.books` doesn't exist since `json` is undefined.

Comment: I defined and called `signInOK()` inside `$(document)ready` and now there is no problem. It just works. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
function getBooks(){
  return $.getJSON( "bookstore.json" );
}

window.getBooksDoneFunc = function(json) { 
  $.each(json.books, function(i, json){ .......... });
}

getBooks().done(getBooksDoneFunc);

$(document)ready(function() {
  function signInOK(){
    var booksJSON = {};
    window.getBooksDoneFunc(booksJSON);
  }
});
```

Comment: You don't need the .call(), just call function.

Comment: What about arguments?  What if it out of scope (my comment to my post)?

Answer (score 1):

If `window["getBooksDoneFunc"]();` works, then does `getBooksDoneFunc()`, the idea of using `window` is when you want to access a global function but you don't know the function name which is stored in a variable.

In your case, put a hardcoding string is mean less, just do `getBooksDoneFunc()` is the same, because you already store the function self (not the string of function name) in the variable.

The thing that won't work is that if  the variable is not global, please check the scope.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this a bit differently, although I do not really understand the signInOK() function. How will it receive the "json" data. I would reconstruct the getBooks function and rethink the signInOk function. Here's a start:

```
function getBooks() {
    $.getJSON("bookstore.json").done(function (json) {
        getBooksDoneFunc(json);
    });
}

var getBooksDoneFunc = function(json) { 
     $.each(json.books, function(i, json){ .......... });

};

...

getBooks();

function signInOK(){
     getBooksDoneFunc("some json data");
}
```

Comment: `getBooks` returns the result of `$.getJSON` which is shorthand for `$.ajax` and that returns a `$.Defered` object which does have a `done` method. http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/