# get/console.log the current namespace

Tags: javascript

I'm experimenting with running a function from a dynamic string...

say I have several functions and i don't want to use 'if else' or inline...

```
yes()
no()
maybe()
sometimes()
whoknows()
random()
```

so I am trying this:

```
window['yes']();
```

but I am stuck with namespace. as I get the error 'global has no method yes' I am not sure how to tell what namespace i am in.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function yes(){console.log('yes?');}

    window['yes']();

    });
```

How do I find out or set the current namespace?

If I did set the namespace how do I start running the code in it immediately or does that just happen on its own?

Comment: As a sidenote, this looks like a really bad idea, and you're probably doing something wrong if this is the only solution to whatever problem you're having ?

Comment: that would be off topic

Comment: I couldn't understand the problem. 
"this" always returns not the current scope, but of the callee (who called the function).
What you try to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to build an api where I receive messages with dynamic function names

Comment: can you make jsfiddle

Comment: I'm only having a problem with a function not being in windows scope, just have no idea how to find out what the current namespace is

Comment: If you are not sure which scope you are in, then you can use console.log(this) to see. In your example 'this' would obviously not contain the method 'yes' since it is never added to 'this'.

Comment: what is the function 'yes' added to if its not in window and not in this?

Comment: look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1723340/990434

Comment: 'yes' is a local variable in the anonymous function you define. And when this anonymous function is called it is bound to the document object. You would have to use `this.yes = function(){};`, but it is not a good idea to add methods to the document object unless you are sure about what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks Adam, your correct, I've learned something new!