# call string function inside jquery document ready without using eval

Tags: jquery

I have a div element in my html code with the class name ".myButton" which holds a data object called

```
data-action="myFunctionToCall"
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="myButton" data-action="startPaymentOverAction">Start Over</a>
```

I also have a jquery document ready object that has my button event inside it.

```
$(function() {

   function myFunctionToCall( arg ){
    console.log("FUNCTION CALLED");
   }

    $('.myButton').click(function( event ){
        var action = $(this).data('action');
        event.preventDefault();
        if(action){
            document[action](event);

        }
    });
});
```

The problem is I can only get this function to work if I use eval.
documentaction; will not work I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: document.paymentOptionAction is not a function". 
How can I get around this without using eval.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723287/calling-a-javascript-function-named-in-a-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to define the function to call, like this:[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/thtbgjfg/)

```
window.startPaymentOverAction=function(event){
  alert('action data');
}

$(function() {

    $('.myButton').click(function( event ){
        var action = $(this).data('action');
        event.preventDefault();
        if(action){
           window[action]( event );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: But that's making it global. I don;t want it to be global

Comment: change window by document then.

Comment: other way is setting the function in an object: [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/thtbgjfg/4/)

Comment: The problem with an object global is I have variables in the document object that the function startPaymentOverActionneeds to get to so it has to stay within that scope.

Comment: I'm using your sample solution but instead of defining the var Objfn = {} outside the jquery document object i'm doing it inside along with the function. that seems to work. Going to try see if it works when I minify the js files, as eval was break because of the minify process.

Answer (score 0):

Your function isn't defined on the document object.  You are inside of a function - `$(function() {`

This simplest way would be:

```
$(function() {
    var that = this;
    function myFunctionToCall( arg ){
        console.log("FUNCTION CALLED");
    }
    $('.myButton').click(function( event ){
        var action = $(this).data('action');
        event.preventDefault();
        if(action){
            that[action](event);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried using the this in a variable but it didn't work.