# How to create a new object of which the name of its super type is assigned to a variable?

Tags: javascript, prototype, eval

I use class syntax for the definition of several prototypes. At a certain point in my code I have to create a new object but which object exactly depends on the prototype name which is stored as a string in a variable.

In [Calling a JavaScript function named in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723287/calling-a-javascript-function-named-in-a-variable) there is a solution to call a function when its name is stored in variable without using `eval()`. How can I achieve the same thing for creating an object from a prototype like this `parser = new VARIABLE_CONTAINING_PROTOTYPENAME`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I'm a huge fan of using strings to represent types, but I don't know your use case, so I won't judge!

To `new` a prototype based on a string, you're probably best off creating a factory function:

```
function factory(name) {
    switch (name) {
        case "Object":
            return new Object();
        case "Array":
            return new Array();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

var myObj = factory("Object");
```

Alternatively, you could create an object and then index into it to get the constructor:

```
var constructors = {
    "Object": Object,
    "Array": Array
};

var myObj = new constructors["Object"];
```

Comment: I must admit that I do not like this approach either though I am not so experienced to think of another approach. The use case goes like this: I have HTML elements on the website that are classified by `data-evnt-type` attribute. When the page is loaded the javascript looks for each element with such an attribute and adds an eventListener to it. When the event is triggered a parser object is created but which parser object depends on the value in the `data-evnt-type` attribute that holds part of the parsers name. Actually the second solution is what I was looking for within this approach

Comment: @CutúChiqueño: Eh, it's not the hackiest thing I've ever seen, and I can't think of a better approach off the top of my head!