# How can I call a function that is contained in a string?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a defined function.

```
$scope.myFunction=function(){
 alert("works")
}
```

I have a variable called `$scope.myVar` and this contains an string that is a function.

```
$scope.myVar="myFunction()";
```

How can I call the function directly from a variable (`$scope.myVar`) and **not** from the defined function(`$scope.myFunction`)?

something like:

$scope.myVar();

this is my code..

http://jsfiddle.net/o0tuvyt2/

```
$scope.myFunction=function(){
 alert("works")
}

    $scope.myVar="myFunction()";

//Execute this:
//$scope.myVar() I dont know
```

Comment: as said in the answers, eval is a possibility.. but its unsafe and generally frowned upon to use eval unless you have a really good reason.  Can you tell us more about your use case and why it has to be a string instead of just binding your variable to a function and invoking it the normal way?

Answer (score 1):

You could `eval` it. This attempts to parse the contents of a string into executable javascript:

```
eval($scope.myVar);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that eval is avoided in 99% of use cases because it's considered dangerous and/or a waste of resources.

Comment: Indeed. If at all possible you want to store references instead, for example `$scope.myVar = myFunction;`

Comment: Why you shouldn't use eval() : https://stackoverflow.com/a/86580/7415107

Answer (score 0):

People tend to jump to `eval`, but the Function constructor is typically a better solution.

Either way there is probably a better solution overall within your use case. Evaluating JS from a string is typically a no-no except in the case of templating. Before implementing anything I would suggest looking at the situation you're trying to solve and try hard to look at it differently. Often times the first step to a better solution is realizing that you can look at a problem from a different perspective.

```js
$scope = {};
$scope.myFunction=function(){
 alert("works")
}

    $scope.myVar= new Function("$scope.myFunction()")();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window context to call your function :

```
window[$scope.myVar](arguments);
```

**Don't use eval**. It's very unsafe.

**Full working example** (with arguments and scope) :

```js
$scope = {};
$scope.myFunction=function(text){
 alert(text);
}

$scope.myVar="myFunction";
$scope.myArgs="great job";


$scope[$scope.myVar]($scope.myArgs);
```

More details here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/359910/7415107

Comment: This will work if `$scope.myVar` is `"myFunction"`, not `"myFunction()"`

Comment: Then just remove parentheses :
$scope.myVar = $scope.myVar.replace(/[{()}]/g, '');

Comment: What if it has arguments inside?

Comment: Yeah, but I'm guessing that's not the only function he's going to use.

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/359910/7415107, there is a full function to do it with arguments, but it don't have to be into the string

Comment: this not works for me.. can you put this in a snipped please?

Comment: Yes in few minutes

Comment: Here it is @yavg

Answer (score 0):

Similar question to this has already been posted.

[Calling a JavaScript function named in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723287/calling-a-javascript-function-named-in-a-variable)

If you read through this post you will see why you should not use eval.

Answer (score 0):

As everybody said, `eval` is very unsafe, but, if you really need to use it, it would be better if you use the angular version because it will evaluate your expression on the current `$scope`.

```
$scope.$eval($scope.myVar)
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval