# Javascript - Statements skipped

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a button in my html:

```
<button id="confirm-download" onclick="submit(getStudentsDetails)" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success">Confirm</button>
```

and these are the `submit` and `getStudentsDetails` functions

```
function submit(callback) {
    $('#download_resumes').attr('action', '/api/studentsdetails/');
    $('#download_resumes').submit();
    callback()
}

function getStudentsDetails() {
    $('#download_resumes').attr('action', '/api/studentsdetails/');
    $('#download_resumes').submit();
}
```

Now these functions are referring to this form:

```
<form  id = "download_resumes" action="api/" method = "POST">
```

The problem here is that, only the **second api** (`/api/studentsdetails/`) is getting called here. I want both of these apis to be called `onClick` of the button.

---

The 2 **API**s that need to be called are `'/api/resumes/'`, `'/api/studentsdetails/'`.

Comment: As soon as you call `.submit()` on your form you've left this page. If you want to stay on this page, you must post the form asynchronously.

Comment: How can i do that asynchronously

Comment: Your question is unclear, which are the two APIs that you want to be called ?

Comment: Please use the search feature!  Here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=submit+form+asynchronously

Comment: @RandyCasburn I couldn't find any relevant answer.

Comment: You do in Dhaval's answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use Handler of submit and then call your second function like the following

```
function submit(callback) {
    $('#download_resumes').attr('action', '/api/studentsdetails/');
    $('#download_resumes').submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  callback()
});
}

function getStudentsDetails() {
    $('#download_resumes').attr('action', '/api/studentsdetails/');
    $('#download_resumes').submit();
}
```

Comment: Instead of `callback()`, I have writted `getStudentsDetails()` and tried this. Seems like both the API's are not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax request to submit form and on success you can call that callback method

```
function submit(callback) {
//assuming callback is method name you want to call 
    $.ajax({
        url:'/api/studentsdetails/',
        data:$('#download_resumes').serialize(),
        success:function(response){
            window[callback]();
        }
    });        
}
```

window[callback] (); will call your callbackmethod on success refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723287/calling-a-javascript-function-named-in-a-variable) for more information.

Comment: I have tried this code. The `api/resumes` is being called and after that I am getting this error in console: `GET http://localhost/api/studentsdetails/?resumes=007 404 (Not Found)`. My API doesn't take queries. How can I handle that?

Comment: 404 means there is no such url, may b you are calling wrong url. check your url may b it is wrong or spelling mistakes or given path is wrong there are many possibilities

Comment: My bad. It needs to be a **POST** request not **GET**. I have added `type: 'POST'` now. The API now is being called but I am not getting the response. Basically its response is a csv file.

Comment: so you are getting data that you want to convert it to csv file right ?, or server is sending csv file as a response ?

Comment: Server should csv file as response!

Comment: are you using mvc ? then check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult) for downloading files