# Call Javascript function in a variable function[solve]

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have a function to clear the user text,but the clearText function is inside the function and variable.

I find some information on Internet,but some solutions are only solve the function in variable and have not two function.

Can anyone tell me how I would call the function in function and variable,please?

And I am sorry about grammar ,English is not my mother language.I am hard to translate using google translate.

[Calling a JavaScript function named in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723287/calling-a-javascript-function-named-in-a-variable)
I try it but got undefined.

```
<script>
    var testing = (function(){
        function clearText(){
            /* call other function in this testing function */
        }
        /* other function */
    })();
    function resetInput() {
        /* I call clearText() function here */
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What does the first function return?

Comment: `return clearText;` then you can use it with `testing` var;

Answer (score 6):

Unless your first function returns `clearText` (or makes it accessible outside of that function in some other way), you cannot use it in `resetInput`.

If it *does* return `clearText`, then you can use it via `testing`:

```js
var testing = (function(){
    function clearText(){
        console.log('clearText() triggered');
        /* some code*/
    }
    /* some function */

    return clearText;    // ****
})();

function resetInput() {
    testing();           // ****
}

resetInput();
```

If it makes `clearText` available in some other way (a global variable, etc.), how you'd use it would depend on what that other way is.

Answer (score 0):

What you are using is **IIFE** *(immediately Invoked Function Expression).* What you do in the following code is inserting the return of *nothing* into the variable `testing`.

Execute the following :

```js
var testing = (function() {
  function clearText() {
    console.log('clearText execution');
  }
})();

console.log(testing);
```

Now what if we return something :

```js
var testing = (function() {
  function clearText() {
    console.log('clearText execution');
  }

  return 'try';
})();

console.log(testing);
```

---

If you want to execute the function `clearText` outside of the IIFE, you have to return a pointer to it, like :

```js
var testing = (function() {
  function clearText() {
    console.log('clearText execution');
    
    return 'done';
  }
  
  return clearText;
})();

console.log(testing);

console.log(testing());
```

---

Now, there is no need for IIFE, you could just store the function inside of object and use the reference :

```js
var testing = {
  clearText: () => {
    console.log('clearText execution');

    return 'done';
  }
};

function resetInput() {
  testing.clearText()
}

resetInput();
```