# How to call a function with a string inside of an object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

I need to call a function from an object with a string. For example:

```
type = 'human'

json: {
    action: 'run',
    type: this.type, //<- Here I want to call a function call 
    'Human', or whatever value has the variable type.
}
```

Basically I want to parse the string and call the function that matches the string.

This is for angular. I'm trying to use window['function'] name but it angular says its not a function.

Thank you!

Comment: To turn a string into code, you're probably looking at using [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), **however** this is generally a bad idea (and a security nightmare) and is often a sign your doing something wrong. Could you just could pass an identifier and then use that to select which function to run instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a JavaScript function named in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723287/calling-a-javascript-function-named-in-a-variable)

Comment: if I use window['functionName'] angular/typescript says the function does not exists. The name of the variable is coming from a http request.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I'm guessing you mean is that you have an object with a property, and the value of that property is ALSO the name of the function you want to call.

For example, maybe you have an array of objects:

```
const obs = [{func:'x',val:2}, {func:'y',val:3}];
```

And you want to iterate over those objects and, for the first one, call a function 'x' and for the second one, call a function 'y'.

One way to do that is to have your functions as part of an object

```
const functions = {
  x: function(val) {
    console.log('inside function x');
    console.log(val);
  },
  y: function(val) {
    console.log('inside function y');
    console.log(val);
  }
}
```

Then, you can do something like this

```
obs.forEach(object => functions[object.func](object.val));
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually we parse the key to call a matched function